# Reasoning behind C++ active exception mechanism

Tags: c++, exception

I recently learned that in C++ there is a single "slot" for an active exception and this raise some questions for me.

The example that I know is something like:

```
void f()
{
    MyClass c;
    throw MyException;
}
```

When we get to the `throw` the function immediately returns and then the exception starts looking for its matching `catch`. But let's say that during the return of `f`, when the destructor of `c` is called, suppose it throws another exception of type `MyException2`, in this case from what I understood the program always crashes because there is only one "slot" for an active exception so when `MyException2` occurs there is a problem.

I would like to know if there is a reason for this specific approach since most other languages have some sort of stack and give a message like `During handling of this exception this other exception occurred`, with clear stack traces for both exceptions.

Is there a reason for this problem not being approached? Things like a stack of active exceptions and if `MyException2` occurs while `MyException1` is active then it will just resolve and then return to the handling of `MyException1`?

I'm sorry if I may not be familiar with the proper terms, this is a purely education question from someone who wishes to know more about the "guts" of the language out of pure fascination.

Comment: This situation is avoided by making sure that destructors do not throw. This is recommended (sternly) in virtually any C++ teaching material.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question. Basically you are just stating "The reasoning for this being implemented the way it is is that this is  the way it is implemented". It's circular logic and doesn't really add anything relevant. I am not looking for a "this is how it works and you have to change the entire language to change that", I'm looking for a "this smart person who implemented it like this did it like this because he/she thought that this and this"

Comment: Also note that you _can_ have multiple exceptions in flight (such as when, within a `catch` block that eventually rethrows the current exception, you `throw` and `catch` another exception). And it's unclear to me what you mean with "it will just resolve and return to handling of `MyException1`". How does it resolve if there are two uncaught exceptions - what if a `catch` matches the outer but not the inner exception?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That isn't really helpful. It seems the asker knows the current state of the language, but is curious *why* this particular set of rules was chosen. In most cases, there is a good reason, though it may be lost in time. (In many cases for C++, that reason is "zero overhead".) That said, SO may not be the best place to ask about this.

Comment: Thank you! Both for the insight and recommendation. Where should I ask about thins then? Although there are bound to be unfriendly people, SO has a history of enormously detailed and insightful answers.

Comment: Disallowing exceptions from destructors (as is directed by the language) exceptions are well behaved.  Allowing exceptions from destructors means that the language cannot guarantee being in a coherent state (and likely is in an invalid state) -- hence the application terminates.  More info on the topic from Stroustrup, Sutter, et al here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#dtors-shouldnt-throw

Comment: @MaxLanghof: You can even have an exception thrown within, but also caught within, a destructor invoked during unwinding for another exception—no `catch` for the outer one involved.  This is why we have `std::uncaught_exceptions` (plural) nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re thinking about in, say, Python looks like

```py
try: risky()
except Error as e:
  some_cleanup(e)
  also_risky()  # raises OtherError
  if still_unhappy(): raise
  more_handling()
```

The corresponding code in C++ behaves the **same** way and does not automatically `terminate`:

```
try {risky();}
catch(const Error &e) {
  some_cleanup(e);
  also_risky();  // throws OtherError
  if(still_unhappy()) throw;
  more_handling();
}
```

The reason is that the original exception **might or might not** have been handled successfully (is `more_handling` *necessary*, or is it just part of retrying?).  C++ makes the optimistic statement that it was, whereas by default Python 3 makes the pessimistic statement that the new exception is fallout from the old.  C++ could of course provide a syntax to indicate the other choice, like Python does (`raise new from None`), but such an “associated exception” would be more difficult still to deal with in a static-typing context than exceptions already are, and one of the main motivations is absent since C++ expects the program to provide whatever backtrace-reporting mechanisms are desired.

The parallel is stronger if you consider **destructors** in both languages (especially in CPython where many of them are reliably invoked during stack unwinding): here, Python simply prints to standard error if a destructor throws, because to do otherwise would greatly complicate its internal resource management.  C++ is actually more permissive in that a destructor **can** throw so long as it was not invoked directly by the unwinding mechanism; this is dangerous, but is occasionally used by experts to good effect.  On the other hand, C++ most certainly does not consider writing to standard error a sufficient option for handling an exception, so if *its* resource management encounters such a problem, it’s all over.